# What is the location of logs when Wso2 EI is run as a docker container

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I pulled the latest WSO2 docker container from docker official website.
Then I ran the following command to run the container

```
docker run -it -p 8280:8280 -p 8243:8243 -p 9443:9443 --name integrator wso2/wso2ei-integrator
```

Where can I find the `wso2carbon.log`?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in docker site itself.

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2ei-integrator
```

Can view the logs with `docker logs integrator` and can access the bash shell of container with  `docker exec -it integrator bash`